# Filling UITableView Cells from an NSMutableArray within a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMutableDictionary that contains NSMutableArrays. The dictionary represents divisions, and the arrays represents the departments within that division. I am trying to fill in the cells of a UITableView from the contents of the NSMutableArray. I currently have the UITableView displaying the correct amount of sections (divisions) and the correct number of cells within each division [departmentArray count];

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    // Return the number of sections.

    return [divisionArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSArray *temp = [divisionDict objectForKey:[divisionArray objectAtIndex:section]];
    return [temp count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSString *temp = [divisionArray objectAtIndex:section];
    if ([temp isEqualToString:@"School of Humanities and Social Sciences"]) 
    {
        temp = @"Humanities and Social Sciences";

    } else  if ([temp isEqualToString:@"School of Science and Mathematics"]) {
        temp = @"Science and Mathematics";
    } else  if ([temp isEqualToString:@"School of Education"]) {
        temp = @"Education";
    }
        return temp;
}
```

I have tried many different things in cellForRowAtIndexPath to display the names of the departments for each division, but I cannot get it to work. I understand I have to get the array for each key, then go through that array and get the names of each dept, but implementing that in cellForRowAtIndexPath is confusing me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping my structure the same, I was able to figure it out, heres the lines I places in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
NSArray *temp = [divisionDict objectForKey:[divisionArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]]];    
[[cell textLabel] setText:[temp objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off changing your structure to have an `NSMutableArray` that contains `NSMutableDictionarys` that contain `NSMutableArrays` for the rows and `NSStrings` for the titles. This I found to be very convenient in some of the code I have been developing.

Here is how is works:

You have an `NSMutableArray` that has an entry for each division, that ends up being a section in the table view.
Within each entry of the array you have an `NSMutableDictionary` that contains a two entries, one that I used the key `@"rows"` for, that contains an array with the rows, and one that I used the key `@"title"` for, that holds the section header.

Your code then becomes:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [divisionArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSArray *rowsInSection = [[divisionArray getObjectAtIndex: section] objectForKey: @"rows"];
    return [rowsInSection count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    NSString *rawTitle = [[divisionArray getObjectAtIndex: section] objectForKey: @"title"];
    NSString *sectionTitle = [rawTitle stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"School of " withString: @""];
    return sectionTitle;
}
```

Comment: I see your logic, but how would I then display the departments of each division in the cells? That is what I am stuck on, the code that does in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: To get the department in the cell itself fetch it from the dictionary in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. Since it gets and index path you know both the section and the row. The section gives you the dictionary with everything you store in it. One of those things is the NSString with the division name and another is an NSArray of rows, from which you get the departments for the division.

As in `numberOfRowsInSection:` above. Once you have the array of rows you can return any one of them just as easily as returning the count.